# Count pages in word document via Powershell without com object

Tags: powershell, ms-word, com

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to count the number of pages in word documents which will end up in a database to be used as a way to assess average number of pages in documents. We have thousands of these word documents which we get from providers and my challenge is that I already have an automated solution in a system without Office apps, meaning no COM object implementation possible.
I've been looking at PSWriteWord as an option but the command for getting page settings seems to only work for margin, size and orientation and does not output a page count. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to tackle this one?
I'm adding the code I tried with PSWriteWord and the results in case someone sees a fluke in my method.

```
Import-Module PSWriteWord
$WordDocument = Get-WordDocument -FilePath 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdocument.docx'
Get-WordPageSettings -WordDocument $WordDocument
```

[image]

Comment: By "no COM", you mean no Office Automation, but you're still on Windows aren't you?

Comment: Correct, still on Windows but no Office installed on that system so I won't be able to do something like "New-Object -ComObject word.application"

Comment: Each Word file is a zipped folder - wherein you find a subfolder "docProps" and within that an xml-file app.xml - there you have a node "pages" which gives you the number of pages of that document.

Comment: The number of pages in a document to some extent relies on the attached printer. That's because Word uses data from the attached printer to optimize the page layout. This sometimes results in the page count varying from one computer to the next for the same document. Word's option to *'scale content for A4 or 8.5x11" paper sizes'* further complicates matters. Anything that relies on XML properties, for example, is therefore unreliable.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is use the [Shell.Application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-application) and the [System.Document.PageCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-document-pagecount) standard Windows property, something like this:

```
$application = New-Object -com "Shell.Application"
$folder = $application.Namespace("c:\myFolder1\myFolder2")
$docfile = $folder.ParseName("myDoc.docx");
Write-Host $docfile.ExtendedProperty("System.Document.PageCount")
```

This is the equivalent of what you'll see in the Shell's Properties dialog, Details tab.

If Word is not installed at all, this method will only be able to read old Word files (.doc format).

For .docx file (Open Xml format), if Word is not installed, you can use Microsoft's [Open Xml SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK). Just download the package from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/), extract it, and copy the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` somewhere (from net46 folder for example) on your disk. This is the only extra file you'll need.

Once you've done that, this other script will dump the page count:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll") | out-null
$doc = [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument]::Open("c:\myFolder1\myFolder2\myDoc.docx", $false)
Write-Host $doc.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.Pages.Text
$doc.Dispose()
```

Comment: I'm getting a blank result on that, if I call the $docfile object props I don't see one for  "PageCount". Here's what the object looks like,                                                          
`code`Application  : System.__ComObject
Parent       : System.__ComObject
Name         : testdocument.docx
Path         : C:\Users\user\Desktop\testdocument.docx
GetLink      :
GetFolder    :
IsLink       : False
IsFolder     : False
IsFileSystem : True
IsBrowsable  : False
ModifyDate   : 4/5/2021 12:18:36 PM
Size         : 23901
Type         : Office Open XML Document `code`

Comment: There's no PageCount property as such, it's a Windows "extended" property with "System.Document.PageCount" being its canonical name. Is the file on an NTFS drive? What does the Shell Properties dialog say, like this one: https://i.imgur.com/pB29gZ3.png

Comment: The file is in an NTFS drive. When I look at the detail window properties tab for the file in a computer with Word installed, it looks like the one in your screenshot, when I look at it in one without Word, the properties are limited to "Name, Type, Folder Path, Size, Date Created, Date Modified, Attibutes, Owner and Computer"

Comment: Yes this code works for .doc (old format) files w/o Word but it needs Word installed on the PC for newer Office Xml docx (.zip) files.

Comment: Thanks Simon, maybe I should update my question to specify both formats doc and docx since we have some legacy files and the majority as Office XML. Not sure if there's a work around for this without Office installed. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've added another script for the docx without Word case.

Comment: Hey Simon, I'm sorry to keep taking up your time but I tried downloading the Open XML package and failed miserably trying to use it. I must mention that the system I'm setting this up in, is isolated from the web and I can only transfer files into it and install them via PowerShell or the command line. I'm getting a `"The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest." ` error when I run your first line referencing the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll file

Comment: Open https://nuget.info/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/2.16.0 and double click on the .dll file, download it somewhere and run your powershell aside that file: https://i.imgur.com/TBGcvRU.png can't help you much farther, should be very easy. There's no such thing as an "install" to do, if your environment is so special that you can't copy a simple file, this is another issue.

Comment: Hey Simon, I finally made it work. For some reason I had to specify the whole path of the location of the dll file. Thanks for all your help, I'll upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to give a little back since I got a lot out of this, in case someone comes to this page wondering how to the get the page count of DOC and DOCX files without Word installed. Thanks to Simon Mourier for pointing me in the right direction, I have taken his answers and turned them into a function. As he said, you'll need to download the file DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll which is contained in the lib\net46 folder within the documentformat.openxml.2.16.0.nupkg file that's available here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/
The function takes a PSObject or a string with the path to the file. I'm only using it to return the page count, but you can return many other properties by editing the return line within the function or maybe adding it as a parameter.

```
function Get-PageCount {
    param (
        $docuName
    )
    if ($docuName -is [string]) {
        $docuName = Get-Item $docuName
    }
    if ($docuName.Extension -eq '.doc') {
        # Process Doc Extension Files
        $application = New-Object -com "Shell.Application"
        $folder = $application.Namespace((Split-Path $docuName))
        $docfile = $folder.ParseName($docuName.Name)
        return $docfile.ExtendedProperty("System.Document.PageCount")
    }
    else {
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path $appFolder 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll')) | out-null # Replace $appFolder with the location where DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll was stored 
        $doc = [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument]::Open($docuName.FullName, $false)
        return $doc.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.Pages.Text
    }
}`
```